# Transparent semi circle in top center of UIView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I want to create a view that looks like this:

[image]

I create three views(Blue, Green and Orange) and when the user taps any view then it should expand. I did everything excepts the transparent semi circle on top center of each view.

Please guide me to create this.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45115304/how-to-crop-the-uiview-with-repeated-semi-circle/45149042#45149042

Comment: you can use CAShapeLayer and UIBezierPath to draw lines, circles and other figures. read about it. you can draw some figure and add it to layer.

Comment: @ReinierMelian Thanks for your quick response. I will check this and let you know.

Comment: @SergeyHleb Thanks for your quick response. I will try Reinier Melian shared link.

Comment: @Sabs, yes, I was saying about this too

Comment: Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407586/cut-a-circle-out-of-a-uiview-using-mask?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa 
Hope this will helps you.

Comment: @RamMohan - Thanks for your reply. And your suggested link is what i needed. Thank you so much.